# How to trace a local function

Tags: common-lisp

I want to trace a local function but the Lisp implementation complains that the function is not defined.

```
(defun calc (a)
  (flet ((inner-calc (a b)
         (+ a b)
         ))
    ;; body of flet
    (trace inner-calc)
    (inner-calc a 10)
    ))

(format t "Result: ~a~%" (calc 10))
```

I tried this with clisp and sbcl on MacOS.

Comment: Yes it is. I searched but did not found it. Thanks.